# Angular, ionic, Service promise, deferred, async

Tags: angularjs, jquery-deferred, ionic-framework

I am trying to use a `service` that runs an asynchronous function.
I am trying to call the factory, then do something only it is resolved.
But it doesn't work, I get the error : `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`

I am declaring the deferred object into the service function and I return its promise.

Can you help me please ?

app.js:

```
angular.module('SnowBoard', ['ionic', 'ngCookies', 'ui.unique', 'SnowBoard.controllers', 'SnowBoard.services'])

.run(["isPhoneGap","connectionStatus", 'updateProDB', "$ionicPlatform", '$q', 'sessionService', 'imagesService', function(isPhoneGap, connectionStatus, updateProDB, $ionicPlatform, $q, sessionService, imagesService) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });


  var promise = updateProDB.get();
  promise.then(
          function(data) { 
              imagesService.checkIfImagesExistAllAtOnce(prodata);
          },
          function(error) {

          });
}])
```

service.js:

```
.service('updateProDB', ['isPhoneGap', 'connectionStatus', 'isIOS', '$q', 'sessionService', function updateProDBFactory(isPhoneGap, connectionStatus, isIOS, $q, sessionService) {
    this.get = function(){

        var debugOptionUseLocalDB=0;
        var prodata=[];
        var gotANewDB;
        var dbReadyDeferred = $q.defer();

        if (typeof debugOptionUseLocalDB != 'undefined' && debugOptionUseLocalDB) {
            fallbackToLocalDBfile();
            return dbReadyDeferred.promise;
            gotANewDB = 1;
            console.log('on a fini fallbackToLocalDBfile, et dbReadyDeferred.state()='+dbReadyDeferred.state());
        }else{
            if(connectionStatus == 'online'){
                console.log("reaching DB on server (getJsonpFile)...");

                getDBfileXHR(dbUrl()).then(function(){ //if resolved
                        console.log(prodata);
                        return dbReadyDeferred.promise;
                    }, function (){ // if rejected
                        console.log("...basic XHR request failed, falling back to local DB file...and sending mail to dev.");
                        fallbackToLocalDBfile();
                        return dbReadyDeferred.promise;
                        var body = ""; 
                        if ( isPhoneGap ) {
                            body += " Platform : phonegap";
                            body += " device.cordova : "+device.cordova;
                            body += " device.model : "+device.model;
                            body += " device.name : "+device.name;
                            body += " device.platform : "+device.platform;
                            body += " device.uuid : "+device.uuid;
                            body += " device.version : "+device.version;
                        } else {
                            body += "Platform : not phonegap -> web browser"
                            body += "navigator.userAgent : "+navigator.userAgent;
                        }
                        var data={
                                userEmail: "louisromain@yahoo.fr",
                                subject: "BoardLine dev issue: had to fallback to local DB file",
                                destEmail: "louisromain@yahoo.fr",
                                body: body           
                               }
                        sendToServer(data).done(funcSuccess).fail(funcError);
                        function funcSuccess(data /* , textStatus, jqXHR */ ) {
                            console.log("Message to dev successfully sent");
                        }
                        function funcError(data , textStatus, jqXHR  ) {
                            console.log("The message to dev could not be sent...");
                        }
                    });


            }else{ //offline
                console.log('device is offline');
                if(localStorage) {
                    if ( isPhoneGap || !isIOS() ) { //BUG iOS safari doesn't work with this (Cf. Philippe's ipad)
                        if (localStorage.getItem("proDB") === null ) { //if proDB exists in localStorage
                            fallbackToLocalDBfile();
                        } else {
                            //popShortToast("...reading DB in localStorage.");
                            var data = JSON.parse(localStorage["proDB"]); //read current localstorage
                            prodata = storeJsonInProdata(data);
                            sessionService.store('prodata', prodata);
                            dbReadyDeferred.resolve(); //initializeSelectButtons();
                            return dbReadyDeferred.promise;
                        }
                    }
                }else{ //if localStorage not available, read local file
                    prodata = fallbackToLocalDBfile();
                    return dbReadyDeferred.promise;
                }
            }
        }

        function getDBfileXHR(url) {
            var getDBfileXHRdeferred = $q.defer();
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.open("GET", url, true); //3rd parameter is sync/async
            request.timeout = 2000;
            //console.log(url);
            request.onreadystatechange = function() {      //Call a function when the state changes.
               if (request.readyState == 4) {
                  if (request.status == 200 || request.status == 0) { 
                     console.log('we get a response from XHR');
                     //popShortToast("...updating DB from server using simple XHR.");
                     var jsonText = request.responseText.replace("callback(", "").replace(");", "");
                     prodata = storeJsonInProdata(JSON.parse(jsonText));
                     sessionService.store('prodata', prodata);
                     // console.log(prodata);
                     gotANewDB = 1; 
                     getDBfileXHRdeferred.resolve();
                     dbReadyDeferred.resolve();
                  } else {
                    console.log('error : request.status = '+request.status);
                    getDBfileXHRdeferred.reject();
                  }
               }
            }
            console.log("Sending XMLHttpRequest...");
            request.send();
            return getDBfileXHRdeferred.promise;
        }
        function dbUrl(){
            return unescape(encodeURIComponent("http://user:pass@boardlineapp.com/app/proDB.jsonp")); //JSONP
        }
        function fallbackToLocalDBfile(){
            getDBfileXHR('proDB.jsonp').then(function(){ //if resolved
                        console.log(prodata);
                        return dbReadyDeferred.promise;
                    });
        }
    }

    function sendToServer(dataToSend) {
        return $.ajax({
            url: 'http://aurel:aurel40@boardlineapp.com/app/mail.php',
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "xml",
            data: dataToSend
        });
    }
    function storeJsonInProdata(data) { //function to store the DB json file into a variable prodata usable in the whole app
        console.log("storing json in prodata");
        //clear prodata first
        var prodata=[];
        //if JSON
        var lines=[];
        for(var i = 0; i <= data.length; i++){
            lines[i]=data[i];
        }
        var fieldnames=lines[0];
        //if tab separated TXT with each model on a separate line
        //      var lines=data.split(/\n/);
        //      var fieldnames=lines[0].split(/\t/);
        var i;
        prodata.push(lines[0]);
        //prodata.push(0);
        for (i = 1; i < lines.length-1; ++i) {
            //if JSON
            var fields=lines[i];
            //if TXT            
            //          var fields=lines[i].split(/\t/);
            //prodata.push(i);          
            var j;
            prodata[i]={};
            prodata[i]['id']=i; //auto id, there is no more 'id' column in the DB file.
            for (j = 0; j < fields.length; ++j) {
                var str=fieldnames[j];
                prodata[i][str]=fields[j];  
            }
        }
        return prodata;
    }

}]);
```

Comment: That's quite a method you have there. Does every path return a promise? I kind of can't tell.

Comment: (Also, in the falling-back-to-local code you have a return followed by setting `gotANewDB` to 1, which won't execute?)

Comment: (Actually, that appears to happen over and over, again in the failure code after the `getDBfileXHR` call, and there's a *lot* of code in there. You might want to take a step back and do a code review.)

Comment: (And why use XMLHttpRequest if you're using AngularJS?)

Comment: (Also, is that a real user:pass in that JSON call you posted? And Ajax post?!)

Comment: (Also, `for (i = 0; i <= data.length; i++) {`, are you sure that's what you want to do?)

Comment: (Also, be wary of declaring `var`s all over--JS is not block scoped; there is *only* global and function scope. IMO it's best to not scatter declarations around.)

Comment: @DaveNewton ;) no not every path returns a promise, just where you can read this :`return dbReadyDeferred.promise;`. Thank you for the line after the return ! Indeed, I corrected those mistakes.  For XMLHttpRequest, I am translating an app from JS/Jquery to AngularJS, so I am changing it bit by bit. XMLHttpRequest works because it is pure javascript. For the user:pass yes !! can you provide a safer solution ? I never managed to get one. For lines = data...ahahah ...yes for now, I'll correct this later. And for `var`, yeah I am a newbie you know, I am going to listen to your advice.

Comment: @DaveNewton, do you know how to manage the promise thing ?

Comment: (Re: the password, I just don't think you should expose it on a wildly popular website, that's all. If not everything returns a promise then you cannot always call `then` on the return value--it looks very much like that's what's happening in your failure case.)

Comment: I mean yes every case return a promise, (sorry I didn't understand correctly, I thought speaking about file "paths"). Can you help with the promise ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65967/discussion-between-louis-and-dave-newton).

Comment: (Moving this comment to an answer, but it's more of a comment-that-needs-formatting.)

Comment: ok I think you're right, there are a few missing `return` I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There *appears* to be at least one path that doesn't not return a value, nutshell is the path where:

```
   !debugOptionUseLocalBD 
&& connectionStats != 'online' 
&& localStorage 
&& (isPhoneGap || !sIOS()) 
&& localStorage.getItem("proDB") === null
```

The `if (connectionStatus == 'online')` also appears to not return anything immediately.

I find the code a bit difficult to follow–the above may not be completely accurate.

That branch only calls `fallbackToLocalDBfile()`, and there appears to be no return. (I *think*.)

```
if (typeof debugOptionUseLocalDB != 'undefined' && debugOptionUseLocalDB) {
  fallbackToLocalDBfile();
  gotANewDB = 1;
  return dbReadyDeferred.promise;
} else {
  if (connectionStatus == 'online') {
    //
    // !!!!!!!!!! HERE !!!!!!!!!!
    //
    getDBfileXHR(dbUrl()).then(function () {
      console.log(prodata);
      return dbReadyDeferred.promise;
    }, function () {
      fallbackToLocalDBfile();

      // The isPhoneGap/etc. and sendToServer() call; elided for clarity
      sendDevMessage();

      return dbReadyDeferred.promise;
    });
  } else {
    if (localStorage) {
      if (isPhoneGap || !isIOS()) { //BUG iOS safari doesn't work with this (Cf. Philippe's ipad)
        if (localStorage.getItem("proDB") === null) {
          //
          // !!!!!!!!!! HERE !!!!!!!!!!
          //
          fallbackToLocalDBfile();
        } else {
          var data = JSON.parse(localStorage["proDB"]);
          prodata = storeJsonInProdata(data);
          sessionService.store('prodata', prodata);
          dbReadyDeferred.resolve();
          return dbReadyDeferred.promise;
        }
      }
    } else {
      prodata = fallbackToLocalDBfile();
      return dbReadyDeferred.promise;
    }
  }
}
```

Not explaining the circumstances under which the error occurs makes it difficult to help further, but it appears there's at least one set of conditions under which you get `undefined` back, and it *may* be the one I'm highlighting here.

Again, this is more or less a stab in the dark. The code is difficult to understand, as it mixes AngularJS, jQuery (AFAICT, re: the `$.ajax` call), raw `XMLHttpRequests`, etc. There are a significant number of issues present that make reasoning about what's happening quite difficult, at least for me.

Comment: Great ! thank you very much @DaveNewton and sorry for my messy code. I am gonna try to clean it up upon your recommendations.

Comment: @Louis It'a definitely a process--it takes time to figure everything out. Instead of trying to convert the entire application at once I'd take it one small step at a time, flatten out the JS code to avoid the "pyramid of doom", and make sure each small piece works before adding more. Trying to take this large chunk of confusing code on all at once is a recipe for pain.

Answer (score 0):

Louis, there's more to this that just ensuring something is returned from all possible branches.

You have to know exactly what to return from each inner function such that `.get()` will ultimately return a promise of `prodata` however derived.

The whole thing can, and should, be done without creating the explicit promises `dbReadyDeferred` and `getDBfileXHRdeferred`. They are unnecessary and the many `return dbReadyDeferred.promise` statements are wrong.

Life is made slightly awkward by using `jQuery.ajax()` in an angular environment. The "proper" solution would be to use `$http()` in place of `jQuery.ajax()` but much can be achieved (or at least attempted) by coercing jQuery promises to $q, thereby guaranteeing that `.get()` always returns an *angualr* promise.

This heavily modified version of the service is untested and probably still needs to be debugged but should give you a good idea of what's required.

```
.service('updateProDB', ['isPhoneGap', 'connectionStatus', 'isIOS', '$q', 'sessionService', function updateProDBFactory(isPhoneGap, connectionStatus, isIOS, $q, sessionService) {
    this.get = function() {
        var debugOptionUseLocalDB = 0;
        if(typeof debugOptionUseLocalDB != 'undefined' && debugOptionUseLocalDB) {
            return fallbackToLocalDBfile();
        } else {
            if(connectionStatus == 'online') {
                console.log("reaching DB on server (getJsonpFile)...");
                return getDBfileXHR(dbUrl()).then(null, function () {
                    console.log("...basic XHR request failed, falling back to local DB file...and sending mail to dev.");
                    return fallbackToLocalDBfile().then(function(prodata) {
                        var body = [];
                        if (isPhoneGap) {
                            body.push("Platform : phonegap");
                            body.push("device.cordova : " + device.cordova);
                            body.push("device.model : " + device.model);
                            body.push("device.name : " + device.name);
                            body.push("device.platform : " + device.platform);
                            body.push("device.uuid : " + device.uuid);
                            body.push("device.version : " + device.version);
                        } else {
                            body.push("Platform : not phonegap -> web browser");
                            body.push("navigator.userAgent : " + navigator.userAgent);
                        }
                        var data = {
                            userEmail: "louisromain@yahoo.fr",
                            subject: "BoardLine dev issue: had to fallback to local DB file",
                            destEmail: "louisromain@yahoo.fr",
                            body: body.join(' ')
                        };
                        return sendToServer(data).then(function() {
                            return prodata;
                        }, function(textStatus) {
                            console.error("The message to dev could not be sent... :" + textStatus);
                            return textStatus;
                        });
                    });
                });
            } else { //offline
                console.log('device is offline');
                if(localStorage) {
                    if (isPhoneGap || !isIOS()) { //BUG iOS safari doesn't work with this (Cf. Philippe's ipad)
                        if (localStorage.getItem("proDB") === null ) { //if proDB doesn't exist in localStorage
                            return fallbackToLocalDBfile();
                        } else {
                            var data = JSON.parse(localStorage["proDB"]); //read current localstorage
                            var prodata = storeJsonInProdata(data);
                            sessionService.store('prodata', prodata);
                            return $q.when(prodata); //promise of prodata
                        }
                    } else {
                        return fallbackToLocalDBfile();
                    }
                } else { //if localStorage not available, read local file
                    return fallbackToLocalDBfile();
                }
            }
        }
        function getDBfileXHR(url) {
            console.log("Sending XMLHttpRequest...");
            var jqXHR = $.ajax({
                url: url,
                dataType: 'json',
                timeout: 2000
            }).then(function(data) {
                var prodata = storeJsonInProdata(data);
                sessionService.store('prodata', prodata);
                return prodata;
            }, function(jqXHR, textstatus, errorThrown) {
                console.error('getDBfileXHR: url=' + url + ': ' + textstatus);
                return textstatus;
            });
            return $q.when(jqXHR);//coerce jQuery promise to angular
        }
        function dbUrl() {
            return unescape(encodeURIComponent("http://user:pass@boardlineapp.com/app/proDB.jsonp")); //JSONP
        }
        function fallbackToLocalDBfile() {
            return getDBfileXHR('proDB.jsonp');
        }
    }

    function sendToServer(dataToSend) {
        var jqXHR = $.ajax({
            url: 'http://aurel:aurel40@boardlineapp.com/app/mail.php',
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "xml",
            data: dataToSend
        }).then(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            return data;
        }, function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.error('sendToServer: dataToSend=' + dataToSend + ': ' + textstatus);
            return textStatus;
        });
        return $q.when(jqXHR);//coerce jQuery promise to angular
    }
    function storeJsonInProdata(lines) { //function to store the DB json file into a variable prodata usable in the whole app
        var i, j;
        console.log("storing json in prodata");
        var prodata = [lines[0]];
        for (i = 1; i < lines.length-1; ++i) {
            prodata[i] = { 'id': i }; //auto id, there is no more 'id' column in the DB file.
            for (j = 0; j < lines[i].length; ++j) {
                prodata[i][lines[0][j]] = lines[i][j];
            }
        }
        return prodata;
    }
}]);
```

I've stuck with the same overall structure as the code in the question but you can (and maybe should) take things further by throwing an Error at each point `fallbackToLocalDBfile(prodata)` is called and handling such errors centrally in a generalised `catch`. That would be cleaner.

I also attempted to tidy up `storeJsonInProdata()`, which will need testing.